# Como configurar server.xml tomcat para que de timeout 502 y 504

Tags: tomcat, timeout

Tengo una aplicación online de la cual me han reportado clientes que en algunas consultas da timeout a los 2 minutos , corresponderían a los errores 502 y 504.

En local no soy capaz de simular esos errores para poder solucionarlo. Por más que he configurado el server.xml cuando lo pruebo no me saltan el timeout.

```html
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                disableUploadTimeout="false" connectionTimeout="20000"        maxPostSize="2" maxThreads="4" redirectPort="8443" />
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal? Después de configurar el server.xml y reiniciar el tomcat, ¿ hay algo más que deba hacer para que funcionen los cambios?

Comment: No estoy seguro de que entiendas bien lo que representan esos errores: un 504 o 502 suelen significar un error de acceso desde tu servidor a otro lado. Si tu servidor no respondiese, tu navegador no podría obtener una respuesta con estado 502/504

Comment: Necesito que en caso de que de ese error se redirija a una web en concreto. ¿Como lo podría hacer?